# SBCL format and read behave different when in slime and terminal

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

[image]

As you can see, the same function `#'test` behaves different between sbcl and shell(eshell is the same with zsh)

Why is that every happen? And how to `format` first and then `print&read-line` in a shell?

I'm using Emacs 27, slime2.26, sbcl2.0.9, uiop 3.3.2, asdf3.3.2-r1 on Gentoo.
Btw, both sbcl uiop and asdf version I use are masked testing(~amd64), is that something to do with it?

Comment: IO can be buffered. Make sure you force the output before you read from a stream.

Comment: That is the reason. Thank you! I recalled that I don't have to do so previously, so how can I foce the output default?

Comment: the function is called force-output